# como hacer que jQuery Validation Plugin ignore un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

Estoy tratando de de hacer que jQuery Validation Plugin ignore un campo que esta oculto pero no lo realiza les dejo el codigo en este link:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mau12/zh68xf3o/1/)

lo que quiero hacer o haga este codigo es que ignore el input con el id="#Id_employe" si no esta selecionada la opcion de STAFF
y si selecionan la opcion STAFF muestra el campo y que el plugin de JQuary Validation no lo Ignore y sea requerido.

trate con ignore pero no funciona alguna idea como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta agregar un form, y tu codigo no tenia un boton que validara tu funcion, así que hice un pequeño ejemplo, creo que estas algo confundido con respecto a rules:, ahí tu defines las reglas que tendra cada uno de tus inputs, para despues definir los mensajes que contendran esas reglas, te recomiento revisar el sitio oficial de [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hidden-case").hide();
    $('#Participating').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'Staff')
      {
        $(".hidden-case").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $(".hidden-case").hide();
      }
    });
});


function validationForm(){
    $("#main-form").validate({
    rules:{
        Participating:{
          required:{
            depends: function(element){
              if('none' == $('#Participating').val()){
                $('#Participating').val('');
                }
                return true;
                }                  
          }
        },       
        Id_employe:{
            digi:true,
            min:1,
            required:true
        },

      },
      messages:{

        Participating:{
          required: "*Campo Obligatorio"
        },
        Id_employe:{
          required: "*Obligatorio"
        }               
      }


    });      
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="main-form">
<div class="form-input">
<label for="Participating" class="required">Participando como</label>
<select class="form-control " name="Participating" id="Participating"/>
        <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
        <option value="Visitante">Visitante</option>
        <option value="Expositor">Expositor</option>
        <option value="Ponente">Ponente</option>
        <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-input hidden-case">
    <label for="Id_employe" class="required">Numero de Empleado</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control hiddeen" name="Id_employe" placeholder="Numero de Empleado" id="Id_employe"/>
</div>
<button onClick="validationForm();">Validar</button>
</form>
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes configurado a #Id_employe como requerido. No está en el html pero sí en la configuración de la librería. Solo calmbiala la propieda de required a falso.

```
Id_employe:{
   ignore: ":hidden",
   rules: {
       something: {
           digi:true,
           min:1,
           required: false
       }
  }
```

Comment: si pero me tira un error de 

TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefinedjquery.validate.js:791:6
    jQuery 6
        check
        checkForm
        form
        validate
        dispatch
        handle